# Using Driver Signing Certificate for Code Signing

Tags: c#, certificate, clickonce, code-signing, driver-signing

When distributing Software (by Microsoft ClickOnce), are there downsides on using an existing Driver Signing Certificate (from GoDaddy) for Code Signing?

Comment: You should be good to go. It's what we do, and we haven't had any issues. The certificate exists to demonstrate that you are who you say you are; it's equally applicable to ClickOnce and drivers. (We got ours from Verisign, but I should think GoDaddy is the same.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any difference using a *kernel code* certficate instead of a *normal* Code-Signing-Certificate. They are both based on the Microsoft Authenticode system but they are - for what I know - on a different level of trust:

- Code-Signing-Certificates: Class 2
- Microsoft-Kernel Code: Class 3

(based on https://www.startssl.com/?app=40 and other CAs)

So basically it's like using a S/MIME Class 2 Certificate instead of Class 1. It offers more 'Security' (more owner validation) but does it job like the Class 1 one.